# How can I identify the manufacturer of our raised floor?

Tags: server-room

I'm managing servers in a 'hand-me-down' computer room, where we have absolutely *no* documentation about the floor system, and I'm attempting to determine who the manufacturer was so that I can then attempt to find the rating load of the floor and stanchions.

I've found [a](http://www.datacenterresources.com/index.cfm/data-center-cooling/raised-floor-solutions/replacement-tiles/) [few](http://www.comxusa.com/replacement-panels) [places](http://www.datacentersolutionsinc.com/products/replacementpanels.html) that sell replacement panels where you can send images, but I'm trying to avoid getting on their mailing lists, as we don't actually need new tiles.

I'm guessing it's a bit to hope for an [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html) for raised floor systems, but are there any methods or resources to identify the panels?  (hopefully without getting on some sales droid's mailing list)

Comment: Send them an email from a throw-away address you keep on gmail?

Comment: In a similar vein to Zoredache's idea - give them your real email address then block theirs in your spam filter if/when they start sending you unwanted junk.

Comment: This Answer maybe a little late (By a Year), but I couldn't resist. My name is Dillon, and I work for a raised floor dealer/installer.If you still need help just send me a picture of the Tile and understructure in question, and I'd be happy to give you an answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried going through patents for raised floor systems (trying to identify the style of the reinforcement), but had absolutely no luck.  In the end, our solution was to pull up enough of them until we finally found one with identifying information still on it.  (it turned out to be a local company, and the same company that supplied our newer perforated tiles).  It also didn't help that people kept claiming the room was a retrofit (yet there was no ramp, you just rolled straight in from the hallway).

Answer (score 3):

Can you post pictures of the tiles and stanchions? I and some other people on Server Fault deal with datacenter environmentals regularly, and might be able to help you.

[Tate](http://tateinc.com/) is the most popular vendor of datacenter flooring, and their [access flooring catalog](http://tateinc.com/products/access_floors.aspx) would be a good place to start. We use their ConCore, but their Aluminum System is also very popular in a lot of datacenters.

[Haworth](http://flooring.haworth.com) is another popular flooring vendor; we use them in our DR site. [Haworth's flooring catalog](http://flooring.haworth.com/access-flooring/data-centers) might be of some help too.

Comment: I suspect if I'm trying to identify just my specific flooring, that this question would qualify as 'too localized' and closed.

Comment: @joe - I suspect you would be correct. You've asked the question in its most appropriate format. But you can always add in an addendum to your qst with the photos. I'll make sure the question stays open for you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I should've posted this an answer, rather than just a comment:

After lifting enough floor tiles (as we were installing extra stanchions in the center of the tiles), we managed to find a tile that still had a sticker from the manufacturer on it.

It might not work for others, but it's worth a try if you're in the same predicament.